# Oracle Developer make a graph from data

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using Oracle developer.

I have a query in Oracle Database that runs and returns one row of data.

Is there a way to automatically have this row of data get inserted into an existing table every hour or any set amount of time?

If so, how do you insert a row that is outputted from a query to be a row in a table?

Answer (score 0):

The result of a query can be inserted in a table like so:

```
INSERT INTO target_table (column1, column2) 
SELECT expression1, expression2
FROM source_table
[WHERE conditions];
```

Also for graphs have you looked at apex.oracle.com ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a job to run every hour and insert the requested data to your table:

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
   job_name           =>  'insert_row',
   job_type           =>  'PLSQL_BLOCK',
   job_action         =>  'BEGIN
                           INSERT INTO MYTABLE SELECT * FROM MY_OTHER_TABLE;
                           END;',
   start_date         =>   sysdate,
   repeat_interval    =>  'FREQ=HOURLY;INTERVAL=1',
   auto_drop          =>   FALSE,
   enabled=>true);
END;
/
```